# Showing that the polynomials of degree at most 9 is a subspace of all polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I haven't been able to answer this question as it seems abstract.

Let $P_n$ be the set of real polynomials of degree at most $n$.
Show that the set $S$ given by
$S=\{p \in P_9: p(2)=p(4)\}$
is a subspace of $P_9$.

I know that I must show the existence of the zero vector, that the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication but I don't know how to do this for such a high degree polynomial. And the fact that the condition is fairly abstract is also confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a secret:

> The degree of the polynomial is completely irrelevant.

i) The set is non-empty since the zero polynomial satisfies the condition trivially, $\mathbb{O}(2) = 0 = \mathbb{O}(4)$.

ii) Take any two polynomials in $S$, say $p(x),q(x)$, and take any scalar $\alpha$.
Since by definition, the sum $(p+q)(x)$ is equal to $p(x)+q(x)$, the evaluation $$(p+q)(2) = p(2)+q(2) \underbrace{=}_{p,q\in S} p(4)+q(4)= (p+q)(4),$$ which means that $(p+q)(2) = (p+q)(4) \implies (p+q)(x)\in S$
Similarly, again by definition, the scalar multiplication $(\alpha p)(x)=\alpha p(x)$. So, $$(\alpha p)(2)= \alpha\cdot p(2) \underbrace{=}_{p\in S} \alpha p(4) = (\alpha p)(4)$$ and again, $(\alpha p)(2) = (\alpha p)(4) \implies (\alpha p)(x) \in S$

Answer (score 0):

You are given that $S$ is the set of polynomials of degree at most $9$ with outputs equal at $x=2$ and $x=4$. To simplify this, write your polynomials in summation notation:

$$p(x) := \sum_{i=0}^9 a_i x^i \qquad q(x) := \sum_{i=0}^9 b_i x^i$$

for $p,q \in S$. Let $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$ (or whichever field you're using) and $p(2) = p(4)$, $q(2) = q(4)$.

Then you must simply show the following:

- The zero polynomial $z(x) := 0$ is in $S$. (What is its degree?)
- $s(x) := \alpha p(x) + \beta q(x) \in S$. (Is $\deg(s(x)) \le 9$? Is it true $s(2) = s(4)$?)

Answer all of those questions and you have your proof.